# How to download a file with RESTFUL cakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP 2.3 and I have two apps on 2 different servers. I am required to download a file from the first server using REST. I have made my applications RestFul and have configured the routes. I am able to post, get, put and delete but I cannot get it done to download the file.
Below is a sample code for a get

```
 public function view($id) {
    $object = $this->Imodel->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Imodel.id' => $id), 'contain' => array()));
    $this->set(array(
        'object' => $object,
        '_serialize' => array('object')
    ));
}
```

I would appreciate any help to download a file with REST, complying with the Restful architecture that I already have in place.

**Edit**
After some time, I finally got it to work. In case someone else runs into the same problem, the whole thing was about understanding cakePHP [HttpSocket](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html) better.
So first on the server where the webservice is registered (where we download the file from), below is my function; its response is a file as explained ([here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files))

```
public function getpdffile($id = NULL){
    $filepath = APP. 'Files/file.pdf'; //path to the file of interest
    $this->response->file($filepath);
    return $this->response;
}
```

Since the file was not public (not in webroot), i had to use [MediaView](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files). Then after setting this, I'd retrieve it for download using [HttpSocket](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html) as shown below:

```
public function download($id = NULL, $fileMine = 'pdf', $fileName = 'file', $download = TRUE){
    $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $filepath = APP. 'Files/myfile.pdf';
    $file = fopen($filepath, 'w');
    $httpSocket->setContentResource($file);
    $link = MAIN_SERVER."rest_models/getpdffile/".$id.".json";
    $httpSocket->get($link);
    fclose($file);
    $this->response->file($filepath);
    return $this->response;
}
```

What I did there was copy the file to the App folder of my server and render it in a view.
I hope it helps someone :-)

Answer (score 1):

On the server which call the file to download :

```
$file = file_get_contents(urlwhereyoudownload) ;
```

And on the server where webservice is register :

```
header('Content-type: $mimetypeoffile');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName."');
readfile("$pathtofile");exit;
```